# Download online XML file using cron

Tags: cron, yahoo-weather-api

I am very new using cron jobs, and I was wondering if there was a way to save this XML file 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=75039' and save it to a folder in my hosting, somewhere like '/urban/test-page/'I have no idea if this is even possible since the file is in another server, so I am unsure if I can do it this way, or if I should just use a VBscript to accomplish this task.

Thanks for any information that might help me with this.

Comment: Try `curl` or `wget`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wget with -P option for specifying the directory to save.

```
wget http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=75039 -P /urban/test-page/
```

and to specify the filename, add -O filename.extension. e.g.:

```
wget http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=75039 -P /urban/test-page/ -O forecast.xml
```

You will need to make sure that the job is run by a user with permissions for the folder you want to save to.

To set this up as a cronjob, running once a day at 1pm, run:

```
0 13 * * * wget http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=75039 -P /urban/test-page/
```

Comment: I am going to test this and I will mark this as an answer if it works properly.

Comment: I'm looking forward to it. :)

Comment: another question, do I have to specify the name of the file?, right now it failed and said it No such file or directory '/domains/html/urban/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/xml/forecastrss.xml/forecastrss?p=75039'

Comment: no, but the directory you want to save to has to exist

Comment: Will it overwrite a file that is already there with the same name? or do I have to delete the file before downloading again? sorry for so many questions, and thanks a million for your help

Comment: No problem, and yes it will overwrite the file if it is the same filename

Comment: I just changed the right path and it downloaded the file!, but it didn't specify the right name or the XML extension, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sure there is, simply add -O filename.xml @RiquelmyMelara

Comment: it gave me a permission error, but I think I just have to change permissions for that, thank you for your help! this have been marked as the answer :)

Comment: You are welcome! If you need assistance with the permissions, just ask

Comment: Well, it looks like I do need assistance with the permission, I am using mediatemple and I am running this job with the admin user, I changed the permissions to the folder and to the file to be overwritten but I am still getting that same error. forecastrss.xml: Permission denied, any thoughts?

Comment: Here is the complete task 'wget http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=75039 -P /home/html/urban/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/xml/ -O forecastrss.xml'

Comment: can you please try it with chmod 777 -R /home/html/urban/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/xml/  @RiquelmyMelara

Comment: it says Cannot write to `forecastrss?p=75039' (Permission denied).

Comment: strange, it's working for me. Can you please try it like this: 
`wget -O /home/html/urban/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/xml/forecastrss.xml http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=75039`

Comment: it worked!!!! this is great! thanks a million @michael, I couldn't have made it without your help!

Comment: You are welcome! Good that it's working! @RiquelmyMelara